Pagination and continuation token in Azure Table Storage Python API
Similar questions asked here but the azure table package has updated significantly since then and that solution doesn't work any more.
I'm using Azure Data Table Package V12.6.0: https://pypi.org/project/azure-data-tables/12.6.0/
For my application that is a chat platform, I'm saving each conversation in a record at the table storage but when a user loads the chat page, I just want to grab 10 result per load with it's continuation token so I can load 10 more on demand.
I've seen several c# examples, and even a Java example, but not a single one for Python.
Here is my code, I use this

results_per_page

But I doesn't seem to be working as I get all 200 records, plus I don't know where to find continuation token.
def get_chat_history(notebook_id: str, user_id: str):
    """
    Get the chat history for a notebook for a user.
    """
    table_service_client = connect_table_storage()
    table_name = os.getenv("AZURE_CHAT_HISTORY_TABLE_NAME")
    table_client = table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name=table_name)

    entities = table_client.query_entities(query_filter=f"NotebookId eq '{notebook_id}' and PartitionKey eq '{user_id}'",
                                           select=["Role", "Content"],
                                           results_per_page=10
                                           )
    chat_history = []
    for entity in entities:
        chat_history.append({
            "Timestamp": entity._metadata["timestamp"],
            "Role": entity["Role"],
            "Content": entity["Content"]
        })

    return chat_history


You can get the get all entities using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-timeout-and-pagination.

@Venkatesan As mentioned in the question, no resource for Python

There is a SDK and older versions of table storage is supporting that https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/0.37.0/ and included the link to the older question. So I suppose the new version should support that too: https://pypi.org/project/azure-data-tables/12.6.0/
I provided the info in the question.

Check the below answer.


For my application that is a chat platform, I'm saving each conversation in a record at the table storage but when a user loads the chat page, I just want to grab 10 result per load with it's continuation token so I can load 10 more on demand.

You can use the below code that result Pagination and continuation using Azure python SDK.
Code:
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient

def get_chat_history(notebook_id: str, user_id: str):

    table_service_client = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string("xxx"
    table_name = "xxx"
    table_client = table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name=table_name)

    entities = table_client.query_entities(query_filter=f"NotebookId eq '{notebook_id}' and PartitionKey eq '{user_id}'",
                                           select=["Role", "Content"],
                                           results_per_page=25
                                           ).by_page(None)
    chat_history = []
    for page in entities:  
        for entity in page: 
            chat_history.append({ 
                "Role": entity["Role"],
                "Content": entity["Content"]
            })
        print(len(chat_history))


get_chat_history("notebook_0", "user_0")

The above code queries the table for entities matching a specific NotebookId and PartitionKey (user_id), selecting only the Role and Content fields, with results paginated by 25 entities per page.
Output:
25
50
75
100
125
150
175
200
225
250


Now, you can execute your logic with for loop for each page.

Thank you. Just another note for other users is that you can get the continuation token by  continuation_token = entities.continuation_token

There is a slight issue. You still get all the results not the first page. The way I suppose it should work is you get 25 result together with the continuation_token and then if you need more, you request for 25 more with token you received earlier and so in. In the example you provided, it just gets all the record inside multiple 25 items array iterator

Is the issue resolved for you?

Not unfortunately. I explained in the previous comment but suppose you have 1 million record, in the solution you wrote in the answer you sill fetch all 1 million record to your python session. So table_client.query_entities(***, results_per_page=25).by_page(None) still brings all the records, not 25 of them and then you have this page iterator so you just divide the results into multiple page. The solution we want here is if you have 1 million data, you fetch 25 results not all of them. Maybe it's a bug within Azure Data Table Python Package V12.6.0

@YasinAmini Raise the issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Have you raised issue?

No I haven't yet. Will do by the end of the week
